# How to get data from today's midnight to Yesterday's midnight

Tags: sql, postgresql, date-arithmetic

I am looking for data from today's midnight to yesterday's midnight. If today's date "2020-06-10 03:20:25". I want createdate between "2020-06-09 00:00:00" TO "2020-06-10 00:00:00"

Comment: select * from mytable where createdate > '2020-06-09 00:00:00' and createdate < '2020-06-10 00:00:00'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `createdate` is a `timestamp` column:

```
where createdate >= date_trunc('day', current_timestamp) - interval '1 day'
  and createdate < date_trunc('day', current_timestamp) + interval '1 day';
```

Comment: I am getting Error
ErrorMessage: timestamp with time zone units "date" not recognized

Comment: date in above is just variables for the start and end dates of the range you are interested in. In other words '2020-06-09 00:00:00'  and '2020-06-10 00:00:00' . So to rewrite: 

```where createdate >= date_trunc(start_date, current_timestamp) - interval '1 day'
  and createdate < date_trunc(end_date, current_timestamp) + interval '1 day';```

Comment: @Sanjay: sorry, should have been `'day'`

Comment: Thank you !!! In my case I need to run report every day so it is today's date, So what I can put in start_date and end_date. It should not be hard coded.

Comment: `current_timestamp` **is** "today's" date

Comment: See the correction to 'day'. I was not paying enough attention to the function used and steered you in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table midnight_test(id int, createdate timestamptz);
insert into midnight_test values (1, '06/08/2020 17:15'), (2, '06/09/2020 00:00'), (3, '06/09/2020 13:25'), (4, '06/10/2020 00:00');
select * from midnight_test where createdate between '06/09/2020 00:00'::timestamptz and '06/10/2020 00:00'::timestamptz;

id |       createdate       
----+------------------------
  2 | 2020-06-09 00:00:00-07
  3 | 2020-06-09 13:25:00-07
  4 | 2020-06-10 00:00:00-07
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `createdate` is data type `timestamp`, it can be as simple as:

```
WHERE createdate >= CURRENT_DATE - 1
AND   createdate <  CURRENT_DATE
```

[`CURRENT_DATE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-CURRENT) returns the current `date`. You can add / subtract `integer` values to add / subtract days.

When compared to a `timestamp`, `date` is coerced to the first instant of that day. So `date '2020-06-09'` equals `timestamp '2020-06-09 00:00:00'`.

BTW, [`BETWEEN` is almost always the wrong tool for timestamps.](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_BETWEEN_.28especially_with_timestamps.29) See:

- [How to add a day/night indicator to a timestamp column?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/267877/3684)