# Get data from today's midnight to yesterday's midnight

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I am trying to get the date range between  today's midnight to yesterday's midnight. I just followed [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62308278/how-to-get-data-from-todays-midnight-to-yesterdays-midnight) but it complains about `date_trunc` not supporting built in function.

I also tried this way but seems not correct.

```
where [startTime] <= Convert(DateTime, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()))
  AND [startTime] >= Convert(DateTime, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()-1))
```

Comment: After today _and_ before yesterday isn't working for you?

Comment: @HABO, Yes. I have a report to run at 1:00AM or 2:00AM in the midnight but I want to get the date range between today's midnight to Yesterday's midnight.

Comment: If you look a little closer at your logic you will see that your are asking for data that is >= TODAY and also <= YESTERDAY.  Seems rather impossible.

Comment: @JMabee, I modified my query. Could you please help me out.

Comment: Your logic is indeed correct now, but unless you provide some sample data and an expected output I am not sure how anyone is going to help.

Comment: The link you reference is for PostgreSQL hence why it doesn't work on SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* what you are asking for is a way to get yesterdays data when running a report early in the morning. (Your references to midnight are a bit confusing).

This is a very common problem, easily solved by first converting values you are comparing against to dates, and the correctly using `>=` (greater than and equals) and `<` (Less than).

I've used a variable for the datetime `@Now1`to allow it to be changed for testing. But in a real query you can substitute `getdate()`.

```
declare @Now datetime2(0) = '2021-07-16 01:00:00.000';

-- Lets see what the values are
select @Now, cast(@Now as date), dateadd(day, -1, cast(@Now as date));

-- Lets use them in a query
select *
from #Test
-- Where the CreatedDate is "greater than or equal to" the start of yesterday
-- Casting @Now to a date gives the start of today, therefore -1 days gives the start of yesterday
where CreatedDate >= dateadd(day, -1, cast(@Now as date));
-- And CreatedDate is "less than" the start of today
and CreatedDate < cast(@Now as date)
```

As an aside I would never use `GETDATE()-1` because its not obvious what the `1` represents. Better to stick to the [`DATEADD()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function and be sure.

Answer (score -1):

```
where [startTime] > CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
  AND [startTime] < CAST(GETDATE()+1 AS DATE)
```

or simpler but slower on large amount of data

```
where cast([startTime] as date)=CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Comment: How do you get yesterday out of today (`GETDATE()`) and tomorrow (`GETDATE()+1`)?

Comment: question is not clear, add +1 or -1 to expand ragne, principle does not change

Comment: The OP wrote "between today's midnight to yesterday's midnight". You're welcome to answer a different question.

Comment: @HABO yesterday's midnight  equals  > today : 00  , today midnight euqals < (today+1):00

Comment: @Xilmiki, your answer does not produce the answer which I am after.  I am looking for last midnight to today's midnight.